# Proof of $\forall a \in \Bbb{R} -a = (-1)a$

Tags: real-numbers

> **Problem.** Prove that $ \forall a \in \Bbb{R}: -a = (-1) a $.

The teacher gave us a proof but I would like to see another :)

---

*Proof by contradiction*

Suppose that $ -a \neq (-1) a $. Then
\begin{align}
-a + a &    \neq (-1) a + a, \\
a + (-a) &    \neq a + (-1) a, \\
0 &    \neq a(1) + a(-1), \\
0 &    \neq a(1+(-1)), \\
0 &    \neq a(0), \\
0 &    \neq (0)a, \\
0 &    \neq 0 \quad (\text{Contradiction!!!})
\end{align}
Therefore, $ \forall a \in \Bbb{R}: -a = (-1) a $. $ \quad \blacksquare $

Is my proof correct?

I already have the proof of $0a=0$

Comment: $(1)a + (-1)a = a(1-1)=0$ by associativity. Is this ok?

Comment: it is not by associativity, it is by Distributivity

Comment: Yes of course!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof looks okay, but the main thing to be concerned about at this level is circularity, and we can't really check that. If you're sure you don't need this result to prove the used results, then you're good.

Comment: I was actually just thinking the same thing.